# How to do Dependency Injection of a service into an interceptor, using $resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I tried the following:

```
$resource(ur'stuff/:thingId',
  {
    someMethod:{
      method: 'GET',
      interceptor: ['OtherService', function(Otherservice){
         console.log('Too bad, not executed...');
         return {
          response: (response) => {
            console.log('Too bad, not executed...');
          }
        }
      }]

    }
  }

)
```

But it does not work. I found some mentions that $resource has particularities compared to $http, but I could not find the right pattern for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly inject service with interceptor, instead you should be wrapping $resource in factory or service and then can use factory dependency into $resource.interceptor to use.

Example is attached below:

```
angular.module('mainModule', ['ngResource']).
factory("MyResource", ['$resource', 'SomeService', function ($resource, SomeService) {
    return $resource(
        '/', {
        someMethod: {
            method: 'GET',
            interceptor: {
                response: function (data) {
                    // here you can use SomeService
                    console.log('response in interceptor', data);
                },
                responseError: function (data) {
                    // here you can use SomeService
                    console.log('error in interceptor', data);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    );
}]);
```

**Way to import service in ES6 way:**

```
import mainModule from './mainModule';

class SomeController {
    constructor($scope, SomeService) {
        this.$scope = $scope;
        this.SomeService= SomeService;
    }
}

SomeController.$inject = ['$scope', 'SomeService'];

mainModule.controller('SomeController', SomeController);
```

In similar fashion you can make factories and services as well.

Comment: looks good, thanks. Now, since I have ES6 here, I have to find out how to import a service into another service.

Comment: Looks fine, I had just forgotten to inject _ as well. some more debug and it should be ok.

Comment: Way to import service in ES6 way is added.

Comment: Thanks. I will accept your answer anyway, but I want to understand everything first. Currently I have a very weird phenomenon. I do polling on that service method, and with the initial request there is no transformation of data, it happens only in the subsequent calls.

Comment: If I pass the promise direclty to the template there is no intercept. i.e :
this.foo = FooService.Foo.GetStuffs();
otherwise if the tpl var if affected only when tghe promise is resolved, it is fine:
 FooService.Foo.GetStuffs().$promise.then((stuffs) => {
      this.foo = stuffs;
 });

I start thinking this could be an angular bug with $resource